# Channel Model Block - Multipath Effect with taps

Tags: gnuradio

I wanted to ask how can I use the taps parameter of the channel model block in gnu radio to emulate a multi-path effect on the channel.

What exactly do the values used in this parameter mean?
Do they describe time delay or the amplitude of the delayed signal?

Thank you in advance.